# if statement in access 2007 report

Tags: ms-access, if-statement, report, ms-access-2007

I have a report in access. in this report two columns for 'Wochenstunden' and 'Überstunden'. and their values 'Stunden' and 'Überstunden', which worked normally. then I changed both values as following:

```
=Wenn([Stunden]=0;'-';[Stunden])

=Wenn([Überstunden]=0;'-';[Überstunden])
```

(Wenn is the if statement in German form)

In the first one, it works perfectly and shows - when value is 0, but in the second one I get error(in report shows #Fehler instead of all values). Both columns are from same table and have similar values. what can the problem be?

Comment: Happens for me if `[Überstunden]` is null. Can you wrap like this? `=Wenn(nz([Überstunden],0)=0;'-';nz([Überstunden],0))`

Answer (score 0):

Change the names of the *controls* (TextBox) to something different from the names of the fields they are bound to, for example:

```
Stunden -> txtStunden
Überstunden -> txtÜberstunden
```

Also, the expressions could be reduced to:

```
=Nz([Stunden];0)
=Nz([Überstunden];0)
```